# Changing app name in App Store changes URL, what about ASO?

Tags: ios, seo, app-store

If I change my app name, the URL changes. Links to the URLs count to ASO, so I would like to know if there's a way to change the name without changing the URL or if the old URL automatically redirect to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If your old link looks like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/your-app-name/id0000000000
```

Then you might cut it down to:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id0000000000
```

And it will still direct to the same app regardless of the name, because identifier of the app doesn't change when you change it's name.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know I could change the URL, I thought the one that App store suggest was uneditable. Thanks! I'm gonna try

Comment: I tried that but if I do what you say, the URL with just de identifier, has a canonical tag to the main one. I'm asking this for SEO. I wanna choose my URL so it remains forever and doesn't change but, being the main one. I don't want other URLs that point to others as the main one.

Comment: @VKR I didn't understand what you wrote here. Your question was about being able to change app's name without changing URL pointing to it. I provided you name-independent solution using app's identifier which is unique.